# Understanding difficult handwriting/calligraphy

Tags: kanji, handwriting, calligraphy

I'm having trouble deciphering this handwriting. So far, I can definitely tell that the first column says 参拾弐 in 大事, and the fourth column says 手本. Really struggling with column two and some of column three (last two kanji are 弐号, but what's the first?)

[image]

<sup>(Click for full image.)</sup>

Comment: Third column should be 第弐号.

Comment: Is there anything you can tell us about the drawing?

Comment: When was it written?

Comment: My guess for line 2: "生?里命"
And is there any chance that this maybe in Chinese? I'm not seeing any kanas on this

Comment: If your question is more of how to read difficult handwriting, I personally try to switch my mind from looking at the end result, but instead thinking of of possible pen/brush movements that could lead into the output. This often works.